# Flutter: How to stop multiple sounds using AudioPlayers

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a program that plays 3 different sounds at the same time. And there is a stop button, when the user clicks on it, all of the sounds must be stopped.

```
  AudioCache playerCache = new AudioCache(); 
  AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();

  void _playFile(String yol) async {
    player = await playerCache.play(yol);
  }

  void cancelPlay() {
    player.stop();
    player.stop();
  }
```

But when cancelPlay method executes, it only stops the last sound. How to stop all of them at once?

Comment: Which package are you using ?

Comment: AudioPlayers package. https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: All files are playing using the same `AudioPlayer` instance ?

Comment: Every time you play a file via `_playFile`, you clobber the existing `player` variable.  You Instead probably should keep, say, a `Set<AudioPlayer>` to keep track of all outstanding play operations (and remove entries when they finish playing or are cancelled).

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the content of `AudioPlayer` instance in `_playFile` function. Just call the method `play()` like this

```
void _playFile(String yol) async {
  await playerCache.play(yol);
  // Do not use player = await playerCache.play(yol);
}
```

Thus, when you invoke `player.stop();`, it will stop all playing file